# How to move my 3D print file on the Z-axis in Creality slicer software?

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, z-axis, software

I am completely new to 3D printing and am borrowing someone else's Ender printer for a school project. I have never used CAD before either.

I used Onshape to create my design and then exported it as a `.stl` file.  When I load the `.stl` file into the Creality slicer software, it loads in the design too large and partially below the platform.

Could anyone explain to me how to center my design so that it sits on top of the platform rather than below it, i.e. move the design up and down on the Z-axis?

[image: Screenshot of the 3D model in Cura software]

Comment: If you are wanting to move the model up and down, that would be the Z-axis. From your picture, it looks as if the model is too big for the build volume of the printer. Please [edit] your question with more information as to which printer, the build volume, etc. The more info you give, the better an answer can be found.

Comment: I don't think the model will fit the print volume, please add addtional information on the print volume and the model height and max diameter.